# Why are the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods not firing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I recently refactored my app to implement the **Command** pattern.  To that end, I am trying to silo all of my functionality into the appropriate command classes.  I have successfully implemented the pattern for all of my commands, with one exception.  I have a command called `HarvestPhotoCommand` that launches a `UIImagePickerController`, and I want to use that command class as the picker's delegate.  Seems straightforward enough, but for some reason the delegate methods are not being invoked.

Here's my code:

```
//Header file
    @interface WSHarvestPhotoCommand : WSCommand
    <
        UINavigationControllerDelegate,
        UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
        MWPhotoBrowserDelegate
    >
    @end

//From the super class header file:
@property (nonatomic, weak) WSMapViewEngine *mapViewEngine;

//Implementation file
-(void)execute
{
    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.navigationBar.barStyle = [WSAppSettings sharedSettings].theme.barStyle;
    [self.mapViewEngine.mapVC presentViewController:_imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
#pragma mark -
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"Please hit me!");
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    NSLog(@"Or me!");
}
```

`WSCommand` is an `NSObject`, as is `self.mapViewEngine`.   `self.mapViewEngine.mapVC` is a `UIViewController`.

I have tried two experiments thus far.  First, I set the delegate protocols on the `mapViewEngine` and made that the delegate; second, I did the same for the `mapVC`.  Both of these experiments worked, meaning the delegate methods were invoked in each of those classes.  That proved my `UIImagePicker` implementation is correct.

So why will the same not work for my command class?  Both it and the `mapViewEngine` are NSObject so I know that's not the problem.  I suppose I could make the `mapViewEngine` or the `mapVC` the delegate, but the whole reason I'm doing this is to de-couple my classes. I've been trying to solve this all night, so I will accept ANY thoughts or suggestions at this point.

Comment: I suspect the instance of WSHarvestPhotoCommand is not being retained properly... So you initialise one, it fires off an imagePickerController.. And is released before the callback happens. You'll need to make an instanceVariable/property (with a strong retain policy) to back this harvestPhotoCommand object

Comment: @Jef your comment nailed it for me.  I actually was already backing the command class with a property on the `mapViewEngine` just for these types of situations.  It turns out I suffered from a late night copy/paste FAIL because I created the property with a **weak** retain policy. Once I switched this to **strong** the delegate held. None of my other commands are acting as delegates yet so I didn't run into it until now.  Excellent debugging for code sight unseen!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (suggested in my previous comment) is a memory management issue, the delegate callbacks are being fired but the object which had been delegate has already been released because it was not backed by a strong pointer.

As DisableR points out the delegation connection did not affect the objects retain count (and you didn't get an exception like you might have two years ago because the delegate has been nil'd out..)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ARC, `delegate` of `UIImagePickerController` is supposed to be `weak`. Which means that after object which is `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` dies `delegate` value of `UIImagePickerController` becomes `nil` automatically.
Your `WSHarvestPhotoCommand` object dies in the memory before you make any taps on `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: Actually the delegate on UIImagePickerController is weak  (or assign) regardless of ARC - it always has been, like almost all of UIKit's delegation patterns..

Comment: Not always - I remember times without having ARC yet - weak there was not present.

Comment: No, the key difference which you are talking about is the difference between the keywords weak and assign, not a result of ARC at all.. And you'll get that (bad access type exception) if you try to send it a message after it dies, not from the 'death' itself.

Comment: yes, you are correct, I already removed previous comment. But one point - weak won't work without ARC for you in your own code. In system frameworks weak will still work because they are compiled with ARC. Just tested - compiler warning "__weak attribute cannot be specified on an automatic variable when ARC is not enabled" and "@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode"